# Onclick of menu item gives a wired toast

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, fragment-tab-host

I am using Drawer functionality and i am using Fragment-TabHost functionality for fragments 
and i am using Sherlock action Library for this

---

Code runs fine but there is a bug in the functionality:: When i click the menu item of the actionBar a toast kind of dialog is displayed as shown in figure below, I have never used toast in the code

Node::keep pressing menu item for 3 sec...then this dialog pops up

[image]

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements OnItemClickListener{

    private DrawerLayout drawlayout=null;
    private ListView listview=null;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle actbardrawertoggle=null;

    private String[] myfriendname=null;
    private String[] myfriendnickname=null;
    private int[] photo=null;
    //Fragment fragment1 = new Fragment1();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         myfriendname = new String[] { "Sunil Gupta", "Abhishek Tripathi","Sandeep Pal", "Amit Verma" };
         myfriendnickname = new String[] { "sunil android", "Abhi cool","Sandy duffer", "Budhiya jokar"};
         photo = new int[] { R.drawable.sunil, R.drawable.abhi, R.drawable.sandy, R.drawable.amit};

         drawlayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
         listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_drawer);

         getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
         getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
         getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
         getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

         drawlayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
         drawlayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

         MenuListAdapter menuadapter=new MenuListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), myfriendname, myfriendnickname, photo); 
         listview.setAdapter(menuadapter);

         actbardrawertoggle= new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawlayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close)
            {
             public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);

            }

         };
         drawlayout.setDrawerListener(actbardrawertoggle);

         listview.setOnItemClickListener(this);

         if (savedInstanceState == null) {
             selectItem(0);
         }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        actbardrawertoggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        actbardrawertoggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
        selectItem(position);

    }


     private void selectItem(int position) {

            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            // Locate Position
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Fragment1 fragment1=new Fragment1();
                ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment1);
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putString("name",myfriendname[position]);
                b.putInt("photo",photo[position]);
                fragment1.setArguments(b);
                break;
            case 1:
                Fragment2 fragment2=new Fragment2();
                ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment2);
                Bundle b1 = new Bundle();
                b1.putString("name",myfriendname[position]);
                b1.putInt("photo",photo[position]);
                fragment2.setArguments(b1);
                break;
            case 2:
                Fragment3 fragment3=new Fragment3();
                ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment3);
                Bundle b2 = new Bundle();
                b2.putString("name",myfriendname[position]);
                b2.putInt("photo",photo[position]);
                fragment3.setArguments(b2);
                break;
            case 3:
                Fragment4 fragment4=new Fragment4();
                ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment4);
                Bundle b3 = new Bundle();
                b3.putString("name",myfriendname[position]);
                b3.putInt("photo",photo[position]);
                fragment4.setArguments(b3);
                break;
            }
            ft.commit();
            listview.setItemChecked(position, true);
            setTitle(myfriendname[position]);
            drawlayout.closeDrawer(listview);
        }

     @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

         if(item.getItemId()==android.R.id.home)
         {
             if(drawlayout.isDrawerOpen(listview))
             {
                 drawlayout.closeDrawer(listview);
             }
             else {
                drawlayout.openDrawer(listview);
            }
         }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }    


     @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater menuInflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
            menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.actionbar_sort_menu, menu);

            return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a bug. It is designed to be like this and it is not related to all files you have posted here but your menu file named actionbar_sort_menu.
In this file you are having probably something like this:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_delete"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
    android:title="@string/menu_delete"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_white_trash"/>
```

And all you need to do is to not use title. But if you want to see a description for that item, so write something for it.

Answer (score 1):

When you long press a `MenuItem` in the `ActionBar`, a [`Toast` is displayed that contains the title of the `MenuItem`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/com/android/internal/view/menu/ActionMenuItemView.java#L240). The `Toast` is empty because you don't have a title for that `MenuItem`.

[From the docs:](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionItems)

> If the action item appears with only the icon, a user can long-press
>   the item to reveal a tool-tip that displays the action title.